# SQL Developer: connection to 12c db resets after each query

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I recently started using SQL Developer to access data from 11g and 12c databases. Every time I connect to a 12c database and execute a query I get a notification that the connection has been reset. Most of the time, data is still returned, other times there is also a broken pipe error. I am seeing this issue using Windows 10 with SQL Developer version 18.1 and High Sierra MacOS with SQL Developer version 17.2.0.188.

There doesn't seem to be any issues connecting to the databases with Python and cx_oracle.

[image: Error Screenshot]

Any ideas what could be causing this issue or where to find logs to get more information?

Comment: Exactly what version of Oracle 12?

Comment: oracle 12.2.0 sql developer v18.3.0.277.2354

Comment: 18.3 has an 18c JDBC driver...that could be causing problems with your 12.2 instance - although it most definitely should not. You could try version 18.2 to see if that's better or use a THICK connection (requires an oracle home/client)

Answer (score 2):

Try to add the following in file sqldeveloper_nodebug.conf:

```
AddVMOption -Doracle.net.disableOob=true
```